# Using isc-dhcp-server to allocate addresses from subnet different from server subnet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp, ubuntu-12.04, isc-dhcp

I'm trying to break my network into different subnets.

Server is located into 192.168.15.0/24 subnet.

I have the following declaration in my dhcp.conf:

> subnet 192.168.15.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>
> ```
> range 192.168.15.100  192.168.15.250;   
> option routers 192.168.15.236;
> ```
>
> };

When I'm trying to change it to another range:

> subnet 192.168.14.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
>
> ```
> range 192.168.14.100  192.168.14.250;   
> option routers 192.168.15.236;
> ```
>
> };

No addresses are allocated. Even if I'm trying to create fixed address:

> host mee-laptop {
>
> ```
>    hardware ethernet 10:(..);
>    fixed-address 192.168.14.115;
> ```
>
> }

Server won't assign this address to my computer.

I tried to created virtual interface in 192.168.14.0/24 subnet, but it didn't help.

Also, when I'm setting my computer address manually it works and I'm able to access 192.168.15.0/24 network as well as 192.168.14.0/24 network, but when I'm creating server virtual interface with address in 14.0/24 network again I'm not able to reach server and other networks from my computer.

**UPDATE**:

My /etc/networking/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
        iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.15.236
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        #broadcast 192.168.240.127
        gateway 192.168.15.254

auth eth0.2
iface eth0.2 inet static
        address 192.168.14.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        vlan-raw-device eth0
```

Here is a part of dhcpd.log with information about my interface:

```
Feb 13 14:26:52 mario dhcpd: uid lease 192.168.15.101 for client 7c:c3:a1:a7:54:c3 is duplicate on 192.168.15.0/24
Feb 13 14:26:52 mario dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.15.98 from 7c:c3:a1:a7:54:c3 via eth0
Feb 13 14:26:52 mario dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.15.98 to 7c:c3:a1:a7:54:c3 via eth0
```

And here is what's going on in tcpdump:

```
14:29:21.498248 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 7c:c3:a1:a7:54:c3, length 300
14:29:21.498469 IP 192.168.15.236.67 > 192.168.15.98.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

Comment: Can you clarify if your 14 and 15 networks are on the same physical network without any router between them ?

Comment: @BertrandSCHITS same physical network, but there is a media converter and router between my computer and server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure what you are trying to achieve. I can see two possibilities:

1. You have TWO subnets with router in between and want to have ONE DHCP server responsible for IP address assignement. In this case you likely should have a look at dhcprelay (which is also a part of isc-dhcp) or so called "ip helper" or "dhcp helper" on a switch / router.
2. You want two SHARE single physical network segment between TWO subnets. In this case you have to put both subnets in `shared-network` statement.

Answer (score 0):

*This should be a comment asking for more information but i don't have enough rep to do that :-/*

You should add details of your network interfaces on the server (ifconfig output) and possibly add the output of /var/log/dhcpd.log (or whatever configuration file you use). You can get information on how to do that on http://prefetch.net/articles/iscdhcpd.html

Dhcpd doesn't give addresses if it hasn't an interface binded to that subnet. It gives an error like

```
No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
```

Tcpdump of dhcp negotiation will be useful as well to debug the problem.

Comment: thanks! I've updated my post with details. Maybe I should remove my host from subnet pool then?

Comment: Double check if you really want netmask 255.255.0.0 in eth0 configuration. I think it collides with the alias on 192.168.14.0/24

Comment: thanks, unfortunately that didn't help. What's strange now, that DHCP assigns me address reserved for another mac address.